# Unable to login with Stack Exchange OpenID on Area 51

Tags: bug, area-51, login, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I get an error message stating

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

The openid.return_to parameter <long url> the request was made with.
```

I can log in fine on other Stack Exchange sites, including this one. I've tried from a couple of different computers. I'm using Firefox.

Comment: SE changed the login mechanism recently, guess it's related - somehow it borked Area 51 login.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Unrelated. This issue has existed for a long time... though I've not really been able to track down *why*. Seems to be intermittent even for people it does affect.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, changed the other one to [tag:bug] as well then. Good luck catching this bug! :)

Comment: @AdamLear This bug is definitely not intermittent for me. If there's any extra information I can provide to you to help track this down, let me know.