# Cannot access my Area 51 account

Tags: bug, area-51, login, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I wanted to commit to a proposal on Area 51 so I filled in my name and email address. After hitting *Commit* I realized that Area 51 created a new unregistered account for me (although I already have an account for SE sites using the email I provided in the form).

As I couldn't find any log-out buttons I decided to clear cookies associated with Area 51 and log in using my default account. To my surprise, I wasn't able to log in and I was presented the following error instead (I removed possibly sensitive information; I can send the exact message to the developers if they find it useful):

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> The openid.return_to parameter (http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/?s=...) does not match the actual URL (https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/?s=...) the request was made with.

What happened?

---

#### Details

- Restarting Firefox doesn't help.

#### Possibly related

- [Unable to login with Stack Exchange OpenID on Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276389/293336)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to log in to Area 51 after I disabled the *HTTPS Everywhere* plugin (thanks to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291957/293336).

Comment: That did the trick for me, I had this on Chrome as well.